# Does anyone know what "involution" means?

Tags: linguistics, diction

It's a word frequently used in China now. Quote from an article: "Originally used by anthropologists to describe self-perpetuating processes that keep agrarian societies from progressing, involution has become a shorthand used by Chinese urbanites to describe the ills of their modern lives: Parents feel intense pressure to provide their children with the very best; children must keep up in the educational rat race; office workers have to clock in a grinding number of hours."

I'm just not sure if a native English speaker understands this word in the same way as Chinese people do. I kind of have a feeling that its use is restricted to Chinese-speaking groups.

And I am not sure if I can use it in language tests like IELTS.
Thank you.

Comment: Several dictionaries do not show this use of the word. Did you consult any of them?

Comment: According to your description, it’s been used in anthropology and in a different sense as slang in an ESL region. Sounds dangerous for a language test.

Comment: Thank you, Anton and Xanne. Yes, I did. No dictionaries I consulted show such use of the word; but it's quite popular in China, that's why I got confused.

Comment: When I googled "involution" two of the main online dictionaries [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/Involution) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/involution)  and others returned definitions. In fact Lexico gives three definitions and Merriam Webster five, most of them concerned with biology and mathematics but also 'complexity'. Apparently it's quite an old word (late middle English) but it's certainly not in common use.

Comment: This open-access paper discusses involution in anthropology in some detail https://ijae.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s41257-019-0021-y

Comment: Generally speaking whatever's happening in an ESL country isn't normative for English as a whole, no matter the population or the influence of that country.

Comment: Thank you all. That's very helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the full OED gives at least a dozen different definitions for ***involution*** - including domain-specific senses in Anatomy, Physiology, Biology, Mathematics, and Geometry. But ***none*** of those definitions looks remotely similar to the "sociological" sense OP claims here is common in China (where they speak *Chinese* anyway, not *English*).

Comment: It's evidently a term in anthropology and sociology (referring to the tendency of some societies to develop increasingly complex rituals for no obvious benefit) which has come into wider usage in some parts of Chinese culture but not in the west. A perfectly respectable term in anthropology since the 1930s, but not one known to the wider public. For this sense see e.g  https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Alexander_Goldenweiser

Comment: It refers to a process of growing increasingly involved or complicated, perhaps exceedingly so, like in the context you provide. I think of it like "evolution" but imagine that growth turning in on itself for whatever reason, thus becoming ingrown, and the more ingrown it gets, it can lead to increasingly painful and even festering complications, so growth that can be detrimental.